# would changing the lower limit of a power series affect radius of convergence

Tags: analysis, power-series

When we change the lower limit of a power series by any finite quantity, would it increase or decrease radius of convergence or no change?

*Clarification of terminology:* There might be confusion about "lower limit" and "upper limit" term.
Let a summation be $$\sum\limits_{i=a}^b a_iz^i$$
Lower limit of summation is meant to be $a$ and upper limit $b$. Typically, power series appear with $a=0$ and $b=\infty$.

These lower and upper limit of summation is what I am talking about in the question.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: Question is unclear. What is the "lower limit of a power series"?

Comment: As far as I know, lower limit of power series is 0

Comment: What I'm asking is, what does "lower limit of a power series" mean?

Comment: Power series in the book I have is defined as ---Singma aiz^i,lower limit of sigma 0 and upper limit of sigma infinite.

Comment: I have edited question.hope "on hold " tag would be taken away.

Comment: Good, but question still not clear to me. Are you asking about changing $\sum_0^{\infty}a_iz^i$ to $\sum_q^{\infty}a_iz^i$ for some positive $q$, that is, simply dropping the first $q$ terms of the power series without changing any of the other coefficients? Does "changing" the lower limit necessarily mean *increasing* it?

Comment: If I make lower limit negative, would it be power series?

Comment: Z will blow up at zero ,which should not be for power series.

Comment: So, in my opinion, changing lower limit means increasing it usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not change the radius of convergence.  If a series $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges then it still converges if the value of $N$ is changed but all else remains the same, and the fact that $a_n$ is of the form $b_n z^n$ doesn't change that.  If $N<M$ then
$$
\sum_{n=N}^L a_n = \sum_{n=N}^M a_n + \sum_{n=M+1}^L a_n
$$
and as $L\to\infty$, the first term on the left does not change.  Thus one has only added a constant to the sequence of partial sums, and "constant" means not changing as $L$ changes, since $L$ is the thing that is approaching $\infty$.  Adding a constant to a sequence does not change whether it converges or not (although it does change the limit).

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $p(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k z^k$ be your power series and $p_n(z):=\sum_{k=0}^n p_k z^k$ some finite partial sum. Then, the function $p_n$ is defined everywhere as it is a polynomial. If $(p-p_n)$ is defined at a point $z$, then $p(z) = (p-p_n)(z)+p_n(z)$.